# JAX-RS exception handling

Tags: rest, cxf, jax-rs

I'm relatively new to REST services in Java. I've created one and everything works fine except error handling. If I make a request with incorrectly formed JSON in it, Jackson JSON processor throws an exception which I unable to catch and I get error 500 in client. Exception follows:

`javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.HashSet out of VALUE_STRING token`

I have no idea how to handle exceptions raised outside my code.
Google suggests using Exception Mappers or Phase Inteceptors. Though I could miss something in search results.
What is the proper way to handle such situations?
Please, advise something. I'm stuck with this problem...

Comment: Here an example: http://blog.nafiux.com/posts/jax-rs-exception-handling/

Comment: Thanks but this question already has an accepted answer and it's been a while since the question itself was asked :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A JAX-RS ExceptionMapper should do the job. Just add a class like below to your code and if you have the exception type right, then you should get the hook to customize the handling.

```
@Provider
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MyException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(MyException ex) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: I thought that mappers allow to handle exceptions thrown from code of the service. That was my mistake. Thank you!

Comment: I found out that Jackson actually has implementation of exception mapper I needed. It lies in package `org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs` and has an expected name `JsonMappingExceptionMapper`. Default implementation returns status code 400 and brief exception describing message. Jackson also has mapper called `JsonParseExceptionMapper` for JSON parsing errors.

Comment: If JsonMappingExceptionMapper is being picked up and you don't want it to be, there is a workaround here: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2722